# GWT DataGrid resizes the columns

Tags: gwt

From what I understand the DataGrid auto resizes the columns.
What I would like is DataGrid to respect the column widths I set, and to show the horizontal scrollers accordingly. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataGrid gives you complete control over the width of its columns.

For example, if you set the width of all columns in pixels except for one column which has a width equal to 100%, then all columns will have exactly the width you specified, except for the percentage column which will shrink or expand based on the width of a DataGrid itself. If you want all columns to have fixed width, then you should set the width of the entire DataGrid explicitly in pixels.

There is also an important `.setMinimumTableWidth` method. You can use it to tell the DataGrid that it can resize with the width of its parent container, but never be smaller than a certain number of pixels. In this case, if a parent container is too small to accommodate all columns at their desired width, the horizontal scrollbar will appear.